# What is dynamic data sampling in federated learning?

Tags: definitions, federated-learning

I am trying to learn about Federated Learning (FL), but I have a question.

What is dynamic data sampling in FL?

> Cai, Lingshuang, et al. "[Dynamic Sample Selection for Federated Learning with Heterogeneous Data in Fog Computing](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9148586/)." ICC 2020-2020 IEEE International Conference on Communications (ICC). IEEE, 2020.

Comment: So, is this the paper where you found the term "dynamic data sample"? Which page? And doesn't that paper already define the term?

Comment: it's defines dynamic data sampling gradient only.

Comment: This is an old question, but could you please quote the part of the paper that mentions "dynamic data sampling gradient" because I don't have access to the paper.